# Ambiguous factory method argument types error when wiring an executorService

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean definition as:

```
<bean id="executor" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" 
      factory-method="newSingleThreadExecutor" destroy-method="shutdownNow" />
```

When loading, this unfortunately causes:

```
Ignoring factory method [public static java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)] of bean 'executor': 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'executor' defined in class path resource [main-config.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory]: Ambiguous factory method argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as factory method arguments?
```

Spring seems to want to use the newSingleThreadExecutor(ThreadFactory) method whereas I just want to use the no argument method.  Any thoughts on why?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. It works fine for me. I'm on 3.2.4. Are you sure you are posting exactly what you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Spring you are using, [but every document for versions above 3.0 state](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) that to supply arguments to the static factory method, you need to use the `<constructor-arg>` within the `<bean>` element.

Specifying

```
<bean id="executor" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" 
  factory-method="newSingleThreadExecutor" destroy-method="shutdownNow" />
```

will use the no-arg method `newSingleThreadExeutor()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several factory methods to make a

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
```

Breadcrumb to the "factory" code:

https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#L88

But here are 2 samples in xml :

With constructor argument:

```
    <bean id="xmlFixedThreadPoolExecutorServiceBean"
          class="java.util.concurrent.Executors"
          factory-method="newFixedThreadPool"
          destroy-method="shutdownNow">
        <constructor-arg value="5" />
    </bean>
```

With no constructor arguments:

```
    <bean id="xmlWorkStealingPoolExecutorServiceBean"
          class="java.util.concurrent.Executors"
          factory-method="newWorkStealingPool"
          destroy-method="shutdownNow"/>
```

see:

the more "abstract" question is "How to create beans in xml...via static factory methods"

see:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-beans-factory-methods#static